# one github account, both personal and for work - how to make it secure?

Tags: security, github

So I do have a github account which has my personal stuff, but it also is a part of the 'organization' I have at work.

Now - the work stuff is sensitive. I really care about it being secure. I want to access it only from my work laptop with full disk encryption, long passwords, 2 factor authorization wherever possible, etc.

On the other hand most of my personal stuff is public. I want to have a convenient access to it from my other machines, home PC, etc.

Is there a way to attach a second login to my account that would not see the organization?
If not - how to secure this in case my home PC is compromised? Is having separate accounts the only option?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)**

Comment: If your work stuff is really that sensitive, you should probably ask someone at work about how to do this, or if you're even allowed to.

Comment: Having separate accounts is probably the wisest option.  What if you were to leave the company?

Comment: If it is really sensitive, then hosting internally might be an even better option. I believe github has internally hosted packages where you install github on your servers...

Answer (score 5):

The best way to solve this problem is to set up a second account for your work.
That's the most secure way. It's better if everything is strictly seperated.

Answer (score 2):

The old saying "don't mix your work life and your private life" also applies to IT systems. Use different accounts for your private work and your paid work. This easily prevents a breach of security in one to also compromise the other. Besides security, there are also other reasons:

- When you communicate, it is obvious which of your statements are from you as a private person and which are from you as an employee of Acme Corp.
- When you create stuff, it is obvious who owns the copyright of your work. You very likely have a contract which says that your employer owns the copyright to everything you create while you are on the clock. When all of your work is in one github account, it might become difficult to tell who has rights to what.